# Should retain count increase after an image rotation?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management

I'm using the following code to rotate an image

http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2010/01/31/iphone-uiimage-rotation-and-scaling/

that's one of the few image transformations that I do before uploading an image to the server, I also have some other transformations: normalize, crop, resize.

Each one of the transformations returns an `(UIImage*)` and I add those functions using a category. I use it like this:

```
UIImage *img = //image from camera;
img = [[[img normalize] rotate] scale] resize];
[upload img];
```

After selecting 3~4 photos from the camera and executing the same code each time I get a Memory Warning message in XCode.

I'm guessing I have a memory leak somewhere (even though im using ARC). I'm not very experienced using the xCode debugging tools, so I started printing the retain count after each method.

```
UIImage *img = //image from camera;
img = [img normalize];
img = [img rotate];  // retain count increases :(
img = [img scale];
img = [img resize];
```

The only operation that increases the retain count is the rotation. Is this normal?

Comment: Please search for "don't use retainCount". You should be able to find several StackOverflow questions and articles saying: retainCount is not reliable for debugging this sort of thing. Use Instruments, specifically the Leaks and Object Allocation instruments, instead.

Comment: I finally solved the issue by using tje xcode profiler. Interpreting the memory usage graph I realized that I didn't have a memory leak but rather a memory intensive operation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only operation that increases the retain count is the rotation. Is this normal?

It's quite possible that the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` call in your `rotate` function ends up retaining the image. If so, it almost certainly also autoreleases the image in keeping with the normal Cocoa memory management rules. Either way, you shouldn't worry about it. As long as your `rotate` function doesn't itself contain any unbalanced `retain` (or `alloc`, `new`, or `copy`) calls, you should expect to be free of leaks. If you do suspect a leak, it's better to track it down with Instruments than by watching `retainCount` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could you tell me if the way I'm manipulating images (adding functions as categories that return a modified copy) is a good way for processing or if the fact that each operation creates a new image is prone to leaks?. Maybe I should find the way to manipulate the current image instead of making and returning copies?

Comment: I don't think it's any more likely to cause leaks, but it can still cause you to run out of memory. If you create several copies of a large image, those will use memory until they're released. From a memory use standpoint you'd be better off combining all those operations into a single transformation and then applying that.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that I didn't actually have a memory leak but rather a very memory intensive operation (it was my normalize function). I manage to reduce the memory usage for that operation and its all working now.